# Workflow that starts onboarding and finishes with another user?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow

I'm trying to create an onboarding workflow for my company and I'm not sure how the best way to go about it would be.

I'd like the HR Manager to select if this is a new/existing/terminating employee, who they are, department, job title etc. I'd like this information sent to that person's supervisor (as specified in the first form), then that supervisor would fill out another form indicating the new employees IT needs (programs, email, etc...), which is then sent to an IT Manager and then, if approved, to an admin.

I can't seem to figure out how the best way to pass the information from the first form that the HR Manager fills out to the second form that the supervisor fills out, or if this is even possible. I'm not sure if I need to use a Site Workflow, multiple list workflows or whatever the recommended solution might be.

Has anyone got an idea of how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `Create Item in List` workflow action to pass data from one list to another. On each list, I'd start a workflow when the item is created. The workflow on the managers' list would create an item in the supervisors' list and email the supervisor the link. The workflow on the supervisors' list would wait until fields are filled out and then create an item for IT Manager. The workflow on IT Manager's form would wait for an approval field to be set, and would then email the admin if the field was set to approved.

Answer (score 1):

Requirements are simple unless we make it complex

My suggestion would be keeping it as simple as possible.

You have **3 different steps**, so better create **3 different list**, and **3 different workflows**.

**Reason**:

Making it different will make you ease

- in customization,
- new person(developer) coming in future can easily understand and modify the workflow.
- Incase of any issue in a workflow. it will hamper the only single process, and not entire cycle.
- Long workflows might stuck, keep small workflows for each module/step.
- Future enhancements will also be easier
- Keeping independent list will help you reporting department wise.

Now, when it comes to forms, I will strongly recommend to go for custom form,

- since such requirements might go on more enhanced in future or new approval steps can get introduced.
- Also will be easier to show data from any step in read-only mode.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possibilities.

One I've done in the past for a similar situation was to create custom list edit forms where the already entered information was in read only fields and the information to be collected had standard form fields. Then the workflow sent an email to each person along the way with a link to the appropriate custom form.

The other possibility is to use a 2010 Platform workflow with the Collect Data from a User task action to get the needed information then copy that into the current item when the task is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data as suggested by others. I think you need to focus on getting the meta data + design right and use lookup values within the lists.

E.g. If HR manager selects "New" employee why not have a _employmentStatus column either as a visible or as a hidden field. It's probably a useful bit of information so it could be visible. (you could have choices including onleave, inactive, apprentice, maternity leave....)

You should store within the employees details (either in the core list, or another lookup list) what IT systems they have access to. So when the manager gets the email to submit the new form, that information is sent to IT in an email and then also logged in an IT Admin list. You might also want to think about adding columns to show the status and permissions level each person has so that it can be referenced quickly by IT when dealing with issues.

Think less about passing parameters, and more about storing the information in a way that will benefit all business units in the long term.

Just my opinion though, I finished a similar project yesterday so it's fresh in my mind.